# python and imaplib: how to download attachment file given the id of the email

Tags: python, gmail, attachment, gmail-imap, imaplib

By using the `search` query, I am able to get the ids of the all the emails. Now I want to download the attachments from those email. How can I implement that? Any advice would be appreciated, stuck here for a day!

EDIT:
This is the `search` query:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
m.login(username, password)
m.select('inbox')
resp, data = m.uid('search', None, 'X-GM-RAW', 'has:attachment filename:xls')
emailids = data[0].split()
```

Answer (score -1):

This has already been answered - in the body of this question:

[Get the Gmail attachment filename without downloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663672/get-the-gmail-attachment-filename-without-downloading-it)

I just used it myself and it works great - although I would suggest prepending the email from the message to the filename so you have some reference point if you're doing this over lots of emails.

Comment: If you read the answer linked, it shows how to download the multipart attachment.