# To copy the attached file in an email.

Tags: python, outlook, imap

I have been able to figure out how to get the name of the attached file in an email. i am just stuck after that. I don't know what to do after that, I have tried using `os.path.join` which just gives the path i want to download the folder to and joins it with the filename. Please suggest something. Thanks.

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com',993)
m.login("UN", "PW")
m.select("Inbox")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "qwerty")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")


    email_body = data[0][1]
    m = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        print(filename)
```

Comment: Take a look on this question:
[get-the-gmail-attachment-filename-without-downloading-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663672/get-the-gmail-attachment-filename-without-downloading-it)

Comment: @MiguelFebres okay so it gets the file to the folder where the python file is. Can you tell me how can you get the file to a specific folder. If you can post your answer as an answer i can accept it as the right answer. 

You're the man!! :D thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the sample from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663672/get-the-gmail-attachment-filename-without-downloading-it) you can set the path when using the open function. (raw string by prefixing the string with r)

```
fp = open(r'c:\tmp\folder\' + filename, 'wb')
fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
fp.close()
print '%s saved!' % filename
```